# is there anything wrong my GUI program code to be showing result by click on submit button?

Tags: python

```
import tkinter

class longdis:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = tkinter.Tk()
        self.top = tkinter.Frame(self.main)
        self.mid = tkinter.Frame(self.main)
        self.mid1 = tkinter.Frame(self.main)
        self.bot = tkinter.Frame(self.main)

        self.top.pack()
        self.mid.pack()
        self.mid1.pack()
        self.bot.pack()

        self.radiov = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.radiov.set(1)

        self.radio1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.mid, text = 'Daytime (6:00 a.m. through 5:59 p.m.)', variable = self.radiov, value = 0.07)
        self.radio2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.mid, text = 'Evening (6:00 p.m. through 11:59 p.m.)', variable = self.radiov, value = 0.12)
        self.radio3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.mid, text = 'Off-Peak (midnight through 5:59 a.m.)', variable = self.radiov, value = 0.05)

        self.radio1.pack()
        self.radio2.pack()
        self.radio3.pack()

        self.title = tkinter.Label(self.top, text ='Rate Catergory')
        self.title2 = tkinter.Label(self.top, text ='Rate Per Minute')

        self.value = tkinter.StringVar()

        self.label1 = tkinter.Label(self.mid1, textvariable = self.value)
        self.label1.pack()
        

        self.title.pack(side = 'left')
        self.title2.pack(side ='left')

        self.enter = tkinter.Entry(self.mid1, text = 'please enter how many minutes: ', width = 2)
        self.enter.pack()

        self.submit = tkinter.Button(self.bot, text ='submit', command = self.cbfunction )
        self.quit = tkinter.Button(self.bot, text = 'close', command = self.main.destroy)
        self.submit.pack(side = 'left')
        self.quit.pack(side = 'left')

    def cbfunction(self):
        t = float(self.enter.get())
        s = float(self.radiov.get())
        result = t*s
        self.value.set(result)
        

        
    
g = longdis()
```

expected result:
[image]

unexpected result:
[image]

the question(cost for per minute):
[image]

as you can see my code and images above, i am getting the 0 for the result with submit button. i don't know what happened, is there anything wrong with my code, can anyone help me out? i will be very appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you tried to add a `submit` button? Did you mean to replace the `close` button or position the two next to each other?

Comment: @quamrana it can be placed next to the close button, and its showing the result when i clicked on it.

Comment: How do you want to print it? on console?

Comment: What happened when you tried to add a `submit` button?

Comment: @quamrana i did try but i can't get the value and return the results. I tried get.() but its kept showing 0 for the result with i clicked it. i will update my question and code now.

Comment: I meant that you show how you've created the `close` button, but not how you created the `Submit` button. You should be able to create a button, even if it does the wrong thing or nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some changes, look the comments. Also the `self.radiov` should be provided integer value not float as `...variable = self.radiov, value = 0.7`

```py
import tkinter

class longdis:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = tkinter.Tk()
        self.top = tkinter.Frame(self.main)
        self.mid = tkinter.Frame(self.main)
        self.mid1 = tkinter.Frame(self.main)
        self.bot = tkinter.Frame(self.main)

        self.top.pack()
        self.mid.pack()
        self.mid1.pack()
        self.bot.pack()

        self.radiov = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.radiov.set(0) # initialize it to 0 i.e. fist radio button

        self.radio1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.mid, text = 'Daytime (6:00 a.m. through 5:59 p.m.)', variable = self.radiov, value = 0)
        self.radio2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.mid, text = 'Evening (6:00 p.m. through 11:59 p.m.)', variable = self.radiov, value = 1)
        self.radio3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.mid, text = 'Off-Peak (midnight through 5:59 a.m.)', variable = self.radiov, value = 2)

        self.radio1.pack()
        self.radio2.pack()
        self.radio3.pack()

        self.title = tkinter.Label(self.top, text ='Rate Catergory')
        self.title2 = tkinter.Label(self.top, text ='\tRate Per Minute')

        self.value = tkinter.StringVar()

        self.label1 = tkinter.Label(self.mid1, textvariable = self.value)
        self.label1.pack()
        

        self.title.pack(side = 'left')
        self.title2.pack(side ='left')

        self.enter = tkinter.Entry(self.mid1, width = 10)
        self.enterlabel = tkinter.Label(self.mid1, text = 'please enter how many minutes: ')
        self.enterlabel.pack(side ='left')
        self.enter.pack(side ='left')

        self.submit = tkinter.Button(self.bot, text = 'submit', command = self.calculate_result)
        self.submit.pack(side = 'left')
        
        self.quit = tkinter.Button(self.bot, text = 'close', command = self.main.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side = 'right')
        
    def calculate_result(self): # handles the submit method
        button_index = self.radiov.get()
        # depending on radio button calculate result
        if(button_index == 0):
            self.cbfunction1()
        if(button_index == 1):
            self.cbfunction2()
        if(button_index == 2):
            self.cbfunction3()
        
    def cbfunction1(self):
        t = float(self.enter.get())
        s = 0.07
        result = t*s
        self.value.set(result)
    def cbfunction2(self):
        t = float(self.enter.get())
        s = 0.12
        result = t*s
        self.value.set(result)
    def cbfunction3(self):
        t = float(self.enter.get())
        s = 0.05
        result = t*s
        self.value.set(result)
        


g = longdis()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: so the "value = 0,1,2" inside the bracket of the button is being assigned to the button_index variable you created?

Comment: cool, can you look at my question again? i just edited it with my old code that wasn't working with change of the value.. i am a bit confused about it.

Comment: Did you mean `self.quit = tkinter.Button(..` or `self.submit = tkinter.Button(...`?

Comment: `s = float(self.radiov.get()` will give you `0,1,2` not `0.7, ...`. Also `self.radio1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.mid, text = 'Daytime (6:00 a.m. through 5:59 p.m.)', variable = self.radiov, value = 0.07)` is not correct, value should be integer like 0,1,2

Comment: Ya that is correct, I just copied the quit row ha ha